# Magento System Attribute Missing in a Attribute Set

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I've created a new attribute set from "Default" attribute set.But the `media_gallery` attribute is missing in the new attribute set.So the image uploader is not showing in product edit section.How do I add that system attribute to the set?

Comment: How had you created a new attribute set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is at least strange. I would suggest trying to re-create an attribute set based on "Default" to check if the problem will happen again.

In any ways, if you want to add a `media_gallery` attribute to your existing attribute set you have to add a record to `eav_entity_attribute` table, where relation of EAV entity to attribute set and group is stored:

```
INSERT INTO eav_entity_attribute 
        SET entity_type_id = 4,
            attribute_set_id = [YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID],
            attribute_group_id = [YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID],
            attribute_id = [ID_OF_YOUR_MEDIA_GALLERY_ATTRIBUTE by default 82],
            sort_order = 4
```

- The `ID_OF_YOUR_MEDIA_GALLERY_ATTRIBUTE` can be found in `eav_attribute` table using the following query:

  ```
  SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'media_gallery'
  ```
- The `YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID` can be found in `eav_attribute_set` table using the following query:

  ```
  SELECT attribute_set_id FROM eav_attribute_set WHERE attribute_set_name = '[GIVEN_NAME_OF_YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_SET]'
  ```
- And the `YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID` can be found in `eav_attribute_group` table using the following query:

  ```
  SELECT attribute_group_id FROM eav_attribute_group WHERE attribute_set_id = [YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID] AND attribute_group_name = 'Images'
  ```

Comment: I do not think there is such a thing as a "default media_gallery attribute" ID. On a plain Magento 1.7.0.2 install with demo data I have the ID 703 for example.

Comment: At my clean install (maybe calling it default was not correct) it is `82`. I provided detailed instructions how to get the actual value. Anyways, thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use PHP to assign attributes to attribute sets:

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
$installer->addAttributeToSet(
    'catalog_product', $attributeSetName, $groupName, $attributeCode
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a programming question, rather it is the question about using Magento as an end-user. I think the question will be deleted soon. However, until it is not, at least this answer may help to solve the problem, thus making people happier.

So all you need is just go to Magento's admin panel -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attribute Sets. Then select your set to open edit page for it. Drag the `media_gallery` attribute from the "Unassigned Attributes" list to the appropriate group in the "Groups" list. Save the attribute set.

That's all :)

Comment: The system attribute is itself missing from the unassigned attribute lists.

Comment: Do I get it right - the attribute is missing from both "Groups" list and from "Unassigned attributes" list? Does it present in the list of all attributes (Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes)?